# how to include only scipy in buildozer?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

in my test project I have been using scipy for some calculations but, for some reason the apk does not open on my phone and there are no errors when compiling.

```
import scipy.stats
```

in specs

```
requirements = python3, kivy, scipy, numpy
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1
```

I'm about to include it to numpy but, the size of the apk will increase, there is some other way to solve this difficulty.
And by the way, I have 3 files:

- main.py
- calculus.py
- design.kv

Comment: @eyllanesc 10 minutes ago I just added it and still does not start. I mean the app starts up the **splash screen** and then **it closes**

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: But the actual problem will be that we don't support scipy on Android. The most realistic options are to use something else, or if the code you need is python-only then to pull it out of scipy into your app.

Comment: @inclement I use the scipy, it's good that they are statistical probabilistic calculations